# Setting FTP mode in PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl, ftp

I have some code that is using the PHP cURL library to upload some files via FTP.

I've been told to switch the FTP mode from passive to active, but I can't find how to do that - there doesn't seem to be an option in the documentation relating to it.  I'm not actually sure what mode it is currently using, or how I can view that.

Comment: there are the CURLOPT_FTP_USE_EPRT and CURLOPT_FTP_USE_EPSV for active/passsive connections.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to this question is to use:

```
$curl = curl_init()
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FTP_USE_EPRT, true);
```

this will allow you to do Active ftp uploads.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the difference between passive and active ftp is that passive always uses the same port while active allows the client to specify the port that the server replies on.

From the CURL man page:

> If you want to switch to active mode
>   you need to use -P/--ftp-port

I think this corresponds to setting the `CURLOPT_FTPPORT` option.

With all that in mind, you'd be better off using the FTP functions (as MetaCipher says)

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using cURL? PHP has a set of FTP functions:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

Comment: Okay... why not re-write it. The difference between active and passive is not just the port, but which side initiates the connection.  

Read more here: http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html

Can you explain more about your underlying problem, and why you are trying to change the mode?

Comment: Rewriting is an option, but it's the last resort.  The point to my question was to find if it is possible to change the FTP mode when using the cURL library.  I know it's very simple to do when using the FTP library, but if it can be done with what I already have then rewriting is not the right solution.  I need to change the mode because the service I'm connecting to is now only accepting active connections.