# cURL Implicit FTPS Connection Timeout

Tags: php, curl, php-curl, ftps, sharefile

I'm trying to upload a txt file (2KB in size) using PHP cURL to Sharefile via implicit FTPS, however I'm receiving:

> Connection timed out after 30000 milliseconds

> Closing connection 0

My code is below, any advice is appreciated:

```
$fp         = fopen($local_file, 'rw+');
$ftp_url    = 'ftps://subdomain.sharefileftp.com/'.$ftp_path;

$ch         = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ftp_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 990);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.':'.$password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLFTPSSL_TRY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH, CURLFTPAUTH_TLS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The output array from `curl_getinfo` is mostly empty values with the url set.

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('curl.txt', 'w+'));` outputs the following (shortened for this post):

```
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x56523a8e1070)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x56523a8e1070)
* TCP_NODELAY set
*   Trying X.X.X.X...
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x56523a8e1070)
* Connection timed out after 30002 milliseconds
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: Do you also need to set `CURLOPT_INFILESIZE`?

Comment: Thank you, I've just added CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, although I'm still getting the same timeout error.

Comment: You might not need INFILESIZE, then. I may just work until EOF. I haven't used curl on php, so I'm trying to draw parallels between the curl C library and the PHP interface.

Comment: I wonder if you've got an active/passive connection mode issue... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717128/setting-ftp-mode-in-php-curl

Comment: I added `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_USE_EPRT, true);` although this has the same timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try adding `CURLOPT_TRANSFERTEXT,true`

I'd try something like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL,TRUE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
$file = 'example.txt';    
$fp = fopen($file, 'r');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ftp://ftp.com/directory/'. $file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pw");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($file));
```

When I get in trouble I add these options
Usually your request header will give you some clues.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);

curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT); `
```